# Is it possible to get the following table layout (using rowspan)?

Tags: html, layout, html-table, row

I'm trying to get an HTML table that looks like the following:

[image]

I currently am trying to use the following markup to get this (basically, I multiplied 4 and 6 together to get 24 and used common factors to try to get what I wanted):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="24">1</td>
            <td rowspan="4">2</td>
            <td rowspan="6">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">4</td>
            <td rowspan="6">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">6</td>
            <td rowspan="6">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">8</td>
            <td rowspan="6">9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">11</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, the above markup doesn't accomplish what I want at all.
Is it possible to get a table like the one shown above using `rowspan`?
If not with `rowspan`, are there other ways to get the table above in HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a table and do `style="transform: rotate(-90deg);"`. /s

Comment: Wait! What? Are you joking? Won't all the text be rotated as well? Also, won't this wreak havoc on screen readers, etc.?

Comment: /s means sarcasm. I was joking! haha. I'm trying to think of a good solution for you.

Comment: Oh, good. I didn't know that /s means "sarcasm". Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same using following html structure

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="24">1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">2</td>
      <td rowspan="6">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">8</td>
      <td rowspan="6">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I see. So basically, I have to add empty `tr` tags so that all the `rowspan` numbers add up. Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Hartleysan - Glad to help you mate!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out...

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
table td {
    width:60px;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-color: black;
}
table th {
    width:60px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-color: black;
}
table th {
 text-align: left
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="12">1</th>
    <th rowspan="2">2</th>
    <th rowspan="3">3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">7</td>
    <td rowspan="3">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```